# three level nested lists generated from 3 database tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a 3 level nested list using information found in 3 separate database tables which are linked togetether thru having common foreign and primary keys.  I have so far figured out how to generate the first two levels of the lists, that is the primary list and it's sublist, however, I need some help in generating the sublist of the sublist.  In order to end up with something similar to:

```
<ul>
<li>List
<ul>
 <li>Sublist
   <ul>
    <li>
    Super_sublist
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<ul>
```

I am using the following code to generate the first part of the list:

```
function get_menu($sql) {
    include 'connect.php';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0);
    $current_album = "";
    $level2 = "";

    echo "<div id='menu'>\n<div class='menu_pos'>\n<ul class='main-navigation'>\n"; 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($current_album <> "" && $current_album <> $row['pageID']) {
        echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
        }
        if ($current_album <> $row['pageID']) {
            echo "<li id='qoute'><a href='".$row['pageURL']."?pageID=".$row['pageID']."'>".$row['page_name']."</a>\n<ul>\n";  

        $current_album = $row['pageID'];
        }
        if ($row['GeneralID'] == NULL) {
            echo "";
        } else {        
        echo "<li><a href='#'>".$row['general_name']."</a>\n</li>";
        }

    }
    echo "</ul>\n</div>\n</div>\n";
}
```

Which results in:

```
    <div id='menu'>
<div class='menu_pos'>
<ul class='main-navigation'>
<li id='qoute'><a href='0?pageID=7'>get quote</a>
<ul>
</ul>
</li>
<li id='qoute'><a href='info.php?pageID=4'>tjänster</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>ovrigt stenarbete</a>
</li><li><a href='#'>lagning av trasiga stenskivor</a>
</li><li><a href='#'>montering av stenmaterial</a>
</li></ul>
</li>
<li id='qoute'><a href='info.php?pageID=3'>produkter</a>
<ul>
</li><li><a href='#'>golvplattor</a>
</li><li><a href='#'>köksbänkskivor</a>
</li><li><a href='#'>diskhoar</a>
</li><li><a href='#'>fönsterbänkar</a>
</li><li><a href='#'>golvplattor</a>
</li><li><a href='#'>fönsterbänkar</a>
</li></ul>
</li>
<li id='qoute'><a href='info.php?pageID=2'>om företaget</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>utställning</a>
</li><li><a href='#'>köpvillkor</a>
</li></ul>
</li>
<li id='qoute'><a href='index.php?pageID=1'>hem</a>
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This data is generated using the following sql query:

```
select page_list.pageID as pageID, page_list.page_name as page_name,
       page_list.pageURL as pageURL, level2_menu.GeneralID as GeneralID,
       level2_menu.gener_name as general_name, level3_menu.deepID as deepID,
       level3_menu.deep_title as deep_title 
FROM page_list 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN level2_menu on page_list.pageID = level2_menu.pageID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN level3_menu on level2_menu.GeneralID = level3_menu.generalID 

UNION

select page_list.pageID as pageID, page_list.page_name as page_name,
       page_list.pageURL as pageURL, level2_menu.GeneralID as GeneralID,
       level2_menu.gener_name as general_name, level3_menu.deepID as deepID,
       level3_menu.deep_title as deep_title 
FROM page_list 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN level2_menu on page_list.pageID = level2_menu.pageID     
   RIGHT  OUTER JOIN level3_menu on level2_menu.GeneralID = level3_menu.generalID 
order by pageID desc
```

This gives the following sql result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/927a0

```
+--------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+
| pageID Ascending 1 | page_name  | pageURL  | GeneralID | general_name  | deepID | deep_title |
+--------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+
|                  7 | get quote  | 0        | NULL      | NULL          | NULL   | NULL       |
|                  4 | tjanster   | info.php | 9         | Title         | NULL   | NULL       |
|                  3 | products   | info.php | 5         | Title 2       | 8      | Subtitle   |
+--------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------+--------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a different way using php

```html
<?php
    $table='page_list';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY ID desc" ;  
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$req.'<br>'.mysqli_error($conn));
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

 $table2='Secondtable';
 $name=$row['NAME'];
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $table2 WHERE Name='$name'";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$req.'<br>'.mysqli_error($conn));
 while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){  
      ?>
 
html elements here using the $row and $row2

<?php ;
}
}
?>
```

of course you gotta modify the $sql the way you want

you can go deep with this as many levels you want and you dont need any common foreign and primary keys. 
I hope this helps

Comment: and mixing MySQL APIs too `mysql_error()` along with being open to an SQL injection. Please don't suggest code that will potentially put their database in danger.

Comment: oh , I seriously didn't know that, I just tried to help, should I delete it ?

Comment: No, not really; it could be a solution for them. You could add a note underneath it, to parametrize their query and links to using prepared statements.

Comment: and that `mysql_error()` should all read as `mysqli_error($conn)` with the added `i` and passing connection to the functions. Those `mysql_` functions do not intermix with the `mysqli_` API.

Comment: you are much more exeprienced in this,you may edit it the way you see it fits and ill accept it right away,  it will be useful to me too , because I always use this method :p

Comment: can you give me a bit more details?  Particularly regarding $name and the part saying "html elements here .."?

Comment: $name is used to loop thought the rows you need in the seconde table, its just an example, and I meant by html elements here that you can use that for an html code you want to be repeated for evry row the loop finds